# I creating the simple menu for sidebar menu in css

Tags: html, css

I am creating the simple menu code using CSS and html, what i want to know it, is it good to pitch the same way or should i use another code or does have any other standard code.

i am trying to create for admin menu sidebar so this is where i am practicing myself with my engaged knowledge's

**I am looking for response at least if my code writing is good or bad**

Thanks
[Here is example of image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJo12.jpg)

```
<main id="main-box">
<section class="section">
 <ul>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i>

      Home</a></li>


      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-check-square" aria-hidden="true"></i>


        Service</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-certificate" aria-hidden="true"></i>



      Products</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-bug" aria-hidden="true"></i>


        Blogs</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-cloud-upload" aria-hidden="true"></i>


          Contact</a></li>


 </ul>
</section>



* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}


body {

font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
background-color :cornsilk;
}




#main-box {
background-color: darkseagreen;
padding: 30px;
display: flex;
align-items: center;


}



.section {
  display: flex;
  width: 70%;
  background:cornflowerblue;
  padding: 20px;
  flex-wrap :wrap

}

.section ul li {
list-style-type: none;
display: list-item;
background-color: violet;
padding:1.5rem;
width: 200px;


}

.section li {
  padding: 10px;


}

.section li a {

  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
  
}

section li i {
  
  padding-right: 10px;
 

}



.section li:hover  {

    enter code here

background-color: red;
cursor: pointer;

}

.section a:hover {
  color:yellowgreen;

}
```

Comment: what do you want !

Comment: is that my code is good or bad practice?

Comment: [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour) might be a better place for this type of question.

Comment: Hi Sai ram, you can post your problems you face in your code here in SO. I suggest you to [take a tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), which will be interesting to understand how SO works :)

Comment: Hai Deepak, created a sidebar menu for creating admin based sidebar, what i want to know, just written some html and css code, so my code is i wrote bad practice or good one, thats what i want to know my friend.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your question lack some context here,and I don't mean it as a disrespect, I am assuming you  started coding very recently, mostly for creating any application most developer use some framework like angular, react, vue, .Net are some of the most used ones, and it is then, when coding practices really matter.
Two of the most important practices in my opinion are:

1.. writing the DRY(Do not repeat yourself) code.

2.. Modular code.

At this point the code looks good.

Comment: Hey Thanks Boss,

Yes I started Learning Html and css, How to write Modular Code and Writing the Dry Code ?

Comment: you should also start with js, also the scope of DRY and Modular code is beyond the scope of a stack overflow question but you can find lot of resources on the same. But start with Js it will help

Comment: Thanks boss, yes i am trying to learn JavaScript but there is lot of games based JavaScript only i found and some are having only react and some kind of js, i want to learn JavaScript ui elements from the scratch i tried so many websites and so many paid videos, still not get understand, i want form validation, sidebar menu arrow up and down and so on.